# A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.DateTime; 

DateTime returnedDate = DateTime.Now();
```

it give me error :

```
A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 
'System.DateTime' is a type not a namespace (line 1, pos 1)
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: Yes, this is not java. You import namespaces, not classes ;p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System; 

DateTime returnedDate = DateTime.Now();
```

Comment: ```DateTime.Now``` is a static property not a method

Comment: @Alex please change the accepted answer to the most-upvoted-answer by dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 18):

> where is my mistake?

It is here: `using System.DateTime;`

`DateTime` is a class inside `System` namespace, not a namespace. In C# you can apply `using` directive only to namespaces. Adding `using XYZ` to your program lets you omit the namespace prefix `XYZ` from classes inside that namespace - for example, to reference class `XYZ.ABC` you can write `ABC`. The `using` directory does not go down to class level, though (this is in contrast to Java's import directories, where `.*` at the end of the name is optional).

Fix this by replacing `using System.DateTime;` with `using System;`

**EDIT :** (in response to a comment by [Karl-Johan Sjögren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547640/karl-johan-sjogren)) There is another `using` construct in C# that lets you create aliases of types. This construct takes class names, but requires you to specify a new name for them, like this:

```
using DT = System.DateTime;
```

Now you can use `DT` in place of `System.DateTime`.

Comment: +1 for explaining it properly. But you can actually use `using` with classes/types to create aliases, such as `using DT = System.DateTime;` and then `DT returnedDate = DT.Now;`.

Comment: but i want it ;_; for not specifing nested enum, like "import static" java feature...

Answer (score 3):

You should use namespace like this way:

```
using system;
```

OR this way with out using namespace:

```
System.DateTime returnedDate = System.DateTime.Now();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System; 

 DateTime returnedDate = DateTime.Now();
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a type which means its a class. 
C# keyword "using" can only be used with namespaces. so in order to use DateTime  class in your code , you don't need to write like this.

```
using System.DateTime;
```

Rather than writing above line,Simply Include System Namespace like this.

```
using System;
```

And use DateTime class in code.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 6 you can do

```
using static System.DateTime;

var now = Now;
```